# Smartface Interstitial Ads

Tags: smartface.io

Although don't support current version of smart face for Admob. Is there any way to create Interstitial Ads (Full screen Ads) with Smartface for the next release for Android and IOS

Answer (score 0):

For the upcoming release(4.5.0), plugin support will be available. Therefore you can generate your own plugins and you will be able to use it as you wish.

Comment: Thank you Merve! When the new release planning to avaliable?

Comment: Some delay on new version? Previous version does not support many functions also 4.3 does not support ios 9 and android 6. It is impossible to prepare commercial apps with smartface by this kind of support, you can not explain your customer  why!

Comment: Beta for 450 is released today, the full version will be available at the end of next week.

Comment: Some news about new version @merve?